# How to disable menu options before open using jQuery Selectric?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectric

I finally found a select menu plugin smart enough to work in IE comparability mode and also allows me to fire an event before the menu options are displaced. This awesome plugin is called [jQuery Selectric](http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/).

I need to fire an event before the options are displayed  and I want to make an ajax request which tells me which option I should enable/disable.

I was able to make the ajax request before the menu opens. but I am having hard time trying to disable the options. The options are always enabled even after I disable them.

I tried to use the `$('select').selectric('refresh');` on ajax sucess but his cause a problem that the menu will never get a chance to open because just before it open the ajax request will close it again.

How can I disable options on the fly?

Here is what I have done

```
    $('#MasterWrapUps').selectric();

    $('#MasterWrapUps').on('selectric-before-open', function (e) {

        var status = "noattempt";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/getStatus",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                if ( data && ! $.isEmptyObject(data) ) {
                    status = data.status;
                }

                attrWrapUpMenu(status);

            }
        });

    });

    function attrWrapUpMenu(status)
    {
        $('.dispositionMenuOption').each(function (index, element) {

            var option = $(element);

            if ( customIsAllowed(status, option) ) {

                option.attr("disabled", false);

            } else {

                if( option.attr('selected') ) {
                    //At this point we know the option that is select can't be used, select the default value
                    $('#MasterWrapUps').val('0')
                }

                option.attr("disabled", true);
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this as a bug in github https://github.com/lcdsantos/jQuery-Selectric/issues/109. The author of the plugin Leonardo Santos at came up with a smart hacky way to solve the problem.

He gave me this code

```
$('#MasterWrapUps').selectric();

var isOpen = false;
var selectricData = $('#MasterWrapUps').data('selectric');

$('#MasterWrapUps').on('selectric-open', function (e) {
    var status = "noattempt";

    if (!isOpen) {
    selectricData.close();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/echo/json/",
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      data: {
        // emulate ajax delay on jsfiddle
        delay: 1
      },
      success: function (data) {
        if ( data && ! $.isEmptyObject(data) ) {
          status = data.status;
        }

        attrWrapUpMenu(status);
      }
    });

  }

});

function customIsAllowed() {
    return !!(Math.random()+.5|0);
}

function attrWrapUpMenu(status) {
  $('.dispositionMenuOption').each(function (index, element) {

    var option = $(element);

    if ( customIsAllowed(status, option) ) {

      option.prop('disabled', false);

    } else {

      if( option.prop('selected') ) {
        $('#MasterWrapUps').val('0');
      }

      option.prop('disabled', true);
    }

  });

  isOpen = true;
  selectricData.refresh();
  selectricData.open();
  isOpen = false;
}
```

The code can also be found in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/lcdsantos/rgaeqbp6/

I hope this code help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot know how long the ajax is going to take to complete, I can think of two possible solutions:

The first is to display a hidden `<div>` over the input and, on click, show a loading image inside it. Then wait until the ajax is over to finally hide the div and [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a click event on the updated `<input>`, or ....

You can launch the update function as soon as the page loads and keep the `<select>` disable until the ajax is complete.

I recommend the second one, but there might be other solutions. If you need any help implementing any of these you should open a new question.

---

**Update**

Since you want to do it after the click, the best I could come up with was this solution. It has the drawback that if the ajax takes too long and the user leaves the select input, it will reopen anyway. But I think this could be fixed with some focus/class verification. I'll leave that in your hands.

I must remind you that this kind of UI might leave some users (the one with bad connection) confused about what is available or not.

```js
$('#MasterWrapUps').selectric().on('selectric-init', function () {
  $('#MasterWrapUps').selectric('open');
});
$('.selectric').on('click', function () {
  setTimeout(function () { /* fake ajax */
    $('option:first-child').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#MasterWrapUps').selectric('refresh');    
  }, 600 );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/jquery.selectric.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/selectric.css">
  <style>.selectric-above .selectric-items {top: 100%; bottom: auto}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="MasterWrapUps">
      <option value="ant">Ant</option>
      <option value="bird">Bird</option>
      <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem here. Alternatively I can set `Async:False` to prevent the next action until ajax request finish. The problem here is how do I get the option to show as disabled after it has been opened. It seems that I have to use the `refresh` function which cause an infinite loop!